How to encode positions of alignment patterns in QR code?
The positions of alignment patterns in the QR code are specified in the annex E of ISO IEC 18004:2015, as in the following.

The alignment patterns are positioned symmetrically on either side of the diagonal running from the top
left corner of the symbol to the bottom right corner. They are spaced as evenly as possible between the
timing pattern and the opposite side of the symbol, any uneven spacing being accommodated between
the timing pattern and the first alignment pattern in the symbol interior.
Table E.1 below shows, for each version, the number of alignment patterns and the row or column
coordinates of the center module of each alignment pattern.

You can check the coordinates(positions) in the PATTERN_POSITION_TABLE from the qrcode.js of the qrcode-generator.
Each row is an arithmetic sequence except the first element 6. The difference $d$ of this sequence is a function of the version $v$. (The version is the width of a QR code in modules(pixels)). The sequence $(d(7), d(8), ..., d(40))$ is (16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 20, 22, 24, 24, 26, 28, 28, 22, 24, 24, 26, 26, 28, 28, 24, 24, 26, 26, 26, 28, 28, 24, 26, 26, 26, 28, 28).
I want an explicit formula of the $d(v)$, as simple as possible, for $v >= 7$. I reached the following formula, which is correct except for $v = 32$.
$$
n = 4v + 17 \\
m = \lfloor (n-14)/28 \rfloor + 1 \\
d = (n - 13 + c) / m \\
c = 2(m-2)(v + 1) \mod 2m
$$
The $n$ is the width of the QR code, $m + 1$ is the length of the sequence, the 3rd formula is from the ideal condition $n = 6.5 \cdot 2 + m d$, and the name of the $c$ means a correction. The 4th formula was obtained by a random trial and error.
Can I get more general formula, without introducing a term such as $\delta_{v,32}$?

I think you can find your answer here:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238704/calculating-the-position-of-qr-code-alignment-patterns      If so,  could someone with permissions close or migrate this question?

The formula is like the following. (It's based on this answer in StackOverflow, as in the comment by Carl Witthoft).
$$
n = 4v + 17 \\
m = \lfloor v/7 \rfloor + 1 \\
d = 2 \left\lceil \frac{\lceil (n-13)/m - 1/2 \rceil}{2} \right\rceil
$$
The key step was the rounding(half down).
